# Custom cell color based on the mysql result contained inside

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page using php/html which displays a dashboard of 8 tables built using 5 MYSQL result sets.
I am wanting to change the background color of various columns based on the value contained in the columns cell.
I have seen a few threads of a similar topic which have got me this far, but none of them could talk me through my specific issues, so I'm hoping someone can enlighten me. :)

***Issue 1.***
The code below works sorta, but it is using only the first result value to define the entire columns cell color, and not individually defining each row in the column.

***Issue 2.***
even if it was working for one result set I'm not sure how to implement it to work with all my other required result sets on the page without copying and pasting the code snippet 8 times with each different result row assigned to = $cellcolor.

In case it is relevant the rows i would like affected are...

- $row_recordset1['check1']
- $row_recordset1['check2']
- $row_recordset1['check3']
- $row_recordset2['rating']
- $row_recordset3['check1']
- $row_recordset3['check2']
- $row_recordset3['check3']
- $row_recordset4['rating']

php Snippet...

```
<?php
$cellcolor=$row_recordset2['rating'];
if (($cellcolor <= 100) && ($cellcolor > 85))
$color = "#C98910";
else if (($cellcolor <= 85) && ($cellcolor > 70))
$color = "#A8A8A8";
else if (($cellcolor <= 70) && ($cellcolor > 65))
$color = "#965A38";
else if ($cellcolor <= 65)
$color = "#000000";
?>
```

Usage snippet...

```
<table border="1">
<tr><td class="table_data">rating</td></tr>
<?php do { ?>
<tr class="profile" align="center">
<td class="rating" bgcolor=<?php echo $color; ?>><a href="rating.php?TargetEvent=<?php echo $row_recordset2['code1']; ?>"><?php echo $row_recordset2['rating']; ?>
</tr>
<?php } while ($row_recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordset2)); ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Try dynamically assigning the td class from a value in the db resultset which matches a css class containing the colour you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to include the logic to set the color within your loop if you want every cell to possibly have a different color. If you have multiple loops and will need to do this multiple times, I would suggest putting the color logic in a function and calling it from within the loop:

Define the function somewhere:

```
<?php
    function get_color($cellcolor)
    {
        $color = "#ffffff";
        if (($cellcolor <= 100) && ($cellcolor > 85)) {
            $color = "#C98910";
        } else if (($cellcolor <= 85) && ($cellcolor > 70)) {
            $color = "#A8A8A8";
        } else if (($cellcolor <= 70) && ($cellcolor > 65)) {
            $color = "#965A38";
        } else if ($cellcolor <= 65) {
            $color = "#000000";
        }
        return $color
    }
?>
```

Updated snippet with the call to get the color:

```
<?php do { ?>
<tr class="profile" align="center">
<td class="rating" bgcolor=<?php echo get_color($row_recordset2['rating']); ?>><a href="rating.php?TargetEvent=<?php echo $row_recordset2['code1']; ?>"><?php echo $row_recordset2['rating']; ?>
</tr>
<?php } while ($row_recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordset2)); ?>
```

This is a simple example of how it could be done without knowing the exact structure/framework. Hopefully it gets you pointed in the right direction ...

Comment: This seems to work well. I can now see how I should of approached it. 
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

php Snippet...

```
<?php
$cellcolor=$row_recordset2['rating'];
if (($cellcolor <= 100) && ($cellcolor > 85))
$color = "Orange";
else if (($cellcolor <= 85) && ($cellcolor > 70))
$color = "Grey";
else if (($cellcolor <= 70) && ($cellcolor > 65))
$color = "Brown";
else if ($cellcolor <= 65)
$color = "Black";
?>
```

Usage snippet...

```
<table border="1">
<tr><td class="table_data">rating</td></tr>
<?php do { ?>
<tr class="profile" align="center">
<td class="rating<?php echo $color; ?>" ><a href="rating.php?TargetEvent=<?php echo $row_recordset2['code1']; ?>"><?php echo $row_recordset2['rating']; ?>
</tr>
<?php } while ($row_recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordset2)); ?>
</table>
```

css file...

```
.ratingOrange {
   background-color: #C98910;
}

.ratingGrey{
   background-color: #A8A8A8;
 }

.ratingBrown{
   background-color: #965A38;
}

.ratingBlack{
   background-color: #000000;
   color: #ffffff;
}
```